# Do the changes made in the panda data frame created don't reflect in the original file?

Tags: python, pandas

I was creating a program to replace all the none values in a data file ( excel sheet) using pandas. for that I first read the excel file and then used the replace method.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A='Book2.xlsx'
dataa=pd.read_excel(A)
dataa[:].replace(np.nan,1,inplace=True)
print(dataa.iloc[3,1])
print(dataa)
```

But the changes reflected only in the read variable (dataa), not in the original file.

[The original excel data file (after code execution), where no changes took place.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TASc4.png)

Please tell if I've done something going wrong, and what to do to resolve this.

Comment: **[No Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)** of code or data. Always provide a [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide data with [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(15).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block.

Comment: `read_excel` does exactly what it says, it reads the file and dumps it into whatever variable you've chosen (`dataa`, in this case). You need to use `to_excel` to "commit" any changes back into .xlsx format.

Comment: @EdKloczko ..Yes...Thank you for the clarification!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not changing the file, you just reading it.

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A='Book2.xlsx'
dataa=pd.read_excel(A)
dataa[:].replace(np.nan,1,inplace=True)
dataa.to_excel("book2_modified.xlsx")
```

The "to_excel" method documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html